# submit button doesn't pass input from textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Basically i have an input box in which an user can type in his email, and a button that submits the email. I can press the button, and it redirects to my "details" page. However, the input from the texbox is not passed to my controller.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label class="margin20">Sign up for newsletter</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, new { name= "mail", Class = "form-control", Style = "display:inline-block; max-width:200px", Placeholder="Example@Example.com" })
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline-block" id="emailSignup"/>
    </div>
}
```

Controllers

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
// GET: Home
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string mail)
{
    return RedirectToAction("details", new {address = mail });
}
public ActionResult details(string address)
{
    EmailSignup person = new EmailSignup { Email = address};
    return View(person);
    }
}
```

i left the model out, because it basically is 1 property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, ...)
```

is generating an input with `name="Email"`.

Note that `new { name = "mail" }` does absolutely nothing fortunately (look at the html your generating) because if it did, it would screw up the model binding process - the whole purpose of using the `HtmlHelper` methods is to bind to your model.

You could change the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string email)
```

and the parameter will be correctly bound, however your method should be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(XXX model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("details", new { address = model.Email });
}
```

where `XXX` is the model that you declared in the view (i.e. with `@model XXX`), so that you get correct model binding and can take into account validation.

Note also that you property should be

```
[Display(Name = "Sign up for newsletter")]
[Required("Please ...")] // assuming you want to ensure a value is submitted
[EmailAddress] // assuming you want a valid email
public string Email { get; set; }
```

and then the view will be

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email) / correctly generates a label associated with the input
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="Example@Example.com" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFOr(m => m.Email)
```

and I recommend adding another class name and using css rather than you inline `style = ".."` element